# .NET WCF Exception

Tags: .net, wcf

I have created WCF + WF service.

I have added the binding and trying to access and execute my WF from my test application, but getting such exception, what does it mean and how do I solve it?

---

The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more         information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from     ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

---

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The is just a generic error that WCF sends back for any fault on the server.  As the error message explains, if you want to see the actual error you need to turn on the `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` in your server config.  This setting looks like this:

```
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="My.ServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Then, WCF will return you the actual error.

Comment: I've added the code, but for some reason it still return the same error.

Comment: @WildGoat can you post your <system.servicemodel> config section?  Are you setting the service behavior on your endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

To send the exceptions to the client, so you can view the exception details there, add the serviceDebug section to your behavior like this:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

You can turn on tracing like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="LFFServicesHost.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Then open the LFFServicesHost.svclog file.  This will show detailed information as to what failed.

Comment: I've added the code, but for some reason it still return the same error.

Comment: Yea, you will still get the error - but with the exception information included you can load your client in debug mode and locate the exception details.